# More elegant/shorter way to conditionally add key-value pair to dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

Is there a more elegant/shorter way to conditionally add a key-value pair to a dictionary in python than this:

```
extra = {'foo': 'bar'}
if something is True:
   extra['some'] = 'thing'
```

Comment: This is elegant enough to me.

Comment: `is True` is redundant, otherwise, just fine.

Comment: @bereal: Omitting `is True` changes the meaning significantly. Dunno if it is intentional or not, but it is certainly not redundant without knowing more.

Comment: @doublep if it changes the semantics, it's likely un-pythonic style because of type-checking vs duck-typing.

Comment: The first line is the definition of the dictionary itself. So you only have two lines, one of which checks if a condition is true. How is `extra['some'] = 'thing'` not elegant/short enough?

Comment: @doublep: Sure, it changes the meaning, but most of the time when a new Python programmer writes `if something is True:` they _really_ should be writing `if something:` instead.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Or maybe `something` is a list of values to accept, while special-cased `True` means "everything is accepted".

Comment: @doublep: Maybe I don't get what you mean. If `something` is a list then `something is True` can never be true! `something is True` can only be true if the name `something` is bound to the `bool` object `True`.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would like it to look, even if it's not valid Python?  That way we can know what you're going for.

Comment: @PM2Ring: E.g. "This attribute can be either a list of additional facets to install or special value `True` meaning 'install all you have'. `None` or an empty list mean there will be no additional facets."

Comment: @doublep; Yeah, ok. But in that case it'd be part of an if..elif.. construction, so it'd be obvious why the code is explicitly testing if `something is True`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using update()

`extra = {'foo': 'bar'}
 extra.update({'some': 'thing'})`

Comment: Update's a nice method, especially for adding multiple key-value pairs, but your code _unconditionally_ adds the new key-value pair, and the crux of the question is how to do it _conditionally_, in an efficient way. I guess you could do `extra.update({'some': 'thing'} if something else {})`, but it's probably _much_ less efficient than the code in the OP. :)